# Not able to display response data in ngDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I am new to ngDialog and i am trying to display response data, received from my service, into ngDialog, my popup is coming and i am able to display static data but when i pass data:$scope.myData, the dynamic value just doesn't populate, Please guide where i am going wrong...
Below is the code.

popup.html:

```
<div>hi how r u</div>
<div>I am fine thank u</div>
```

Controller code:

```
paymentSearchApp.controller('paymentSearchCtrl', function (getXmlService,paymentSearchService,paymentSearchResponse,paymentDetailService,auditHistoryService,errorLogService,accountingEntryService, notesService,$scope, $q, ngDialog) {
getXmlService.getXmlDatafunction().then(
  function(response){
    $scope.xmldata = response;
    console.log($scope.xmldata);
    ngDialog.open({
         template: 'showXml.html',
         className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
         data: $scope.xmldata
        });
    }, function(error){}
)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close!

You can indeed use the `data` key for the object passed to `ngDialog.open` in order to inject data in your dialogs' scope.
However, the data object isn't directly overriding the scope's potentially already existing properties: it is available in `$scope.ngDialogData`.

For example, considering the following code:

```
ngDialog.open({
  template: 'dialogTemplate',
  data: {
    ip: res.data.origin
  }
});
```

You'll find the `ip` information, within your dialog template, by referring to: `{{ngDialogData.ip}}`.

For illustration, check the snippet below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDialog']);

myApp.factory('PaymentSearchSvc', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getXmlDataFunction: $http.get.bind($http, 'https://httpbin.org/ip')
  };
}]);

myApp.controller('PaymentSearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngDialog', 'PaymentSearchSvc', function($scope, ngDialog, paymentSearchSvc) {
  $scope.process = function() {
    paymentSearchSvc.getXmlDataFunction().then(function(response) {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: 'dialogTemplate',
        data: {
          ip: response.data.origin
        }
      });
    });
  };
}]);
```

```css
.text-primary {
  color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.6.4/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.6.4/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css">

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PaymentSearchCtrl">
    <button ng-click="process()">What's my IP?</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogTemplate">
    <h1>Dialog content</h1>
    <p>
      Your IP address is: <span class="text-primary">{{::ngDialogData.ip}}</span>
    </p>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use controller, to pass data to view, as i am noticing here that you haven't use controller as well , let me show you,

```
getXmlService.getXmlDatafunction().then(
  function(response){
    $scope.xmldata = response;
    console.log($scope.xmldata);
    ngDialog.open({
         template: 'showXml.html',
         className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
         controller: ['$scope', function($scope) { 
                 $scope.data = $scope.xmldata
                 // Controller logic here
         }]
        });
    }, function(error){}
)
```

Else here is the another demo from one of answer from stackoverflow : [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YHgXxqKwvjYpWPsFtlw1?p=preview)

Let me know.

Comment: I have updated my controller snippet in the  question, do i really need to create an inner controller? i am already calling ngDialog.open inside my paymentSearchCtrl controller, please advice...

Comment: Actually this is just a one of way, you can pass data from controller to view, i don't know exactly how you are passing or using ngDialog i your app. Please refer ngDialog docs for more info.

Comment: @pranayanand Nah, you don't actually need to create an inner controller. What a hassle that would be! Check out my answer for more details.